# Does riak 2.0 allow object updates to be atomic with solr updates?

Tags: solr, riak

When I update an object that which is being indexed by solr, I enter an inconsistent state between riak and solr.  <strike>Is it possible to create a post commit hook to inform me when the update to solr has been completed so that I can guarantee that the cluster is consistent?  Or do I have to think of a more</strike>  Is there a clever way to handle eventual consistency?

Here are reproducible steps that describe the problem:

```
curl localhost:8098/buckets/bucket/keys/3eaVbY3BWgIN3BFv4riEc6cAqPk -d'{ "key":"3eaVbY3BWgIN3BFv4riEc6cAqPk" }' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
curl -i -XDELETE localhost:8098/buckets/bucket/keys/3eaVbY3BWgIN3BFv4riEc6cAqPk && curl 'localhost:8098/search/query/index_name?q=key:3eaVbY3BWgIN3BFv4riEc6cAqPk&wt=json'

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.5 (jokes are better explained)
Date: Mon, 29 Dec 2014 21:31:58 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0

{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":6,"params":{"q":"key:3eaVbY3BWgIN3BFv4riEc6cAqPk","shards":"127.0.0.1:8093/internal_solr/index_name","127.0.0.1:8093":"(_yz_pn:62 AND (_yz_fpn:62)) OR _yz_pn:61 OR _yz_pn:58 OR _yz_pn:55 OR _yz_pn:52 OR _yz_pn:49 OR _yz_pn:46 OR _yz_pn:43 OR _yz_pn:40 OR _yz_pn:37 OR _yz_pn:34 OR _yz_pn:31 OR _yz_pn:28 OR _yz_pn:25 OR _yz_pn:22 OR _yz_pn:19 OR _yz_pn:16 OR _yz_pn:13 OR _yz_pn:10 OR _yz_pn:7 OR _yz_pn:4 OR _yz_pn:1","wt":"json"}},
    "response":{
       "numFound":1,"start":0,"maxScore":2.9095426,"docs":[              
           {
              "key":"3eaVbY3BWgIN3BFv4riEc6cAqPk",
              "_yz_id":"1*default*index_name*3eaVbY3BWgIN3BFv4riEc6cAqPk*4",
              "_yz_rk":"3eaVbY3BWgIN3BFv4riEc6cAqPk",
              "_yz_rt":"default",
              "_yz_rb":"index_name"
           }
        ]
      }
  }
```

Comment: are you sure the inconsistency is solr updating later than riak?  I thought solr was updated via precommit hook, i.e. before riak gets updated, so the inconsistency would be resolved prior to the client getting a success response for the put.

Comment: @Joe thanks for the comment.  That may be true, but I am still seeing eventual consistency issues.  I didn't word my question too well, so I put an example in to help.  If you can't reproduce it let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Using Yokozuna search in Riak 2.0+, the search indexes are updated by the riak_kv_vnode module [here](https://github.com/basho/riak_kv/blob/2.0.2/src/riak_kv_vnode.erl#L1419).  This means that the index function is not called via precommit hook like it was in legacy search, instead is called asynchronously after the put process has passed the object to be stored to the backend, i.e. after the reply has been sent to the client.

The code that acutally performs the indexing is [here](https://github.com/basho/yokozuna/blob/2.0.0/src/yz_kv.erl#L189-L276).  I don't see any place in there that would permit a notification event or hook without needing to compile the module from source.

I would expect that index process would finish rather quickly, but it could leave a window perhaps as large a several seconds between the object being updated in kv and the corresponding update appearing in the search index.